# Why this command destroyed my ubuntu 14:04 installation?

Tags: linux, shell, xargs, dpkg

I successfully used this command to remove all the old kernels from my system:

```
dpkg --list |
    grep linux-image |
    awk '{ print $2 }' |
    sort -V |
    sed -n '/'"linux-image-3.13.0-100-generic"'/q;p' |
    xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

But when I used this modified version to un-install `cups`,  `dpkg` started to remove packages unrelated to `cups`:

```
dpkg --list |
    grep cups |
    awk '{ print $2 }' |
    sort -V |
    xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

By the time I realized what was happening, my system had became already unbootable. I don't know if it's supposed to happen with `xargs`, but I could not stop the execution with a <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> sequence.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format code in posts, don't use HTML.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not system administration.

Comment: This question could be in http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @Barmar Could you at least explain why HTML should not be used ?

Comment: Because it doesn't format as nicely as using a normal code block.

Comment: @Barmar bash is a command language, so my question is a programming question

Comment: It looks to me like your question is about `apt-get`, not `bash`.

Comment: Or maybe it's about how keyboard interrupts work in interactive shells, which is not really a programming question. It's about using Unix.

Comment: Thanks for the nice editing of my comment, by the way. I admit that my question would have already been answered if I had asked it on Super User or Unix & Linux, but why instead of criticizing so much things of so little importance, you don't start answering at least the part you know of my question ? How keyboard interrupts work in interactive shells ? Why I wasn't able to stop dpkg with Ctrl+C ?